# Python Gedit plugin with GTK, tree store filter runtime recursion error

Tags: python, plugins, gtk, pygtk, gedit

I have a problem writing a gedit plugin in python, using PyGTK.

The basic job of the plugin is to filter a tree store basing the text typed in a text entry. The search is a 'live' search, that is, there are no button to press, the search is performed on the event 'key_release_event' which is handled by the method .refilter() of the tree filter:

```
widget.connect('key_release_event', self.on_type_search_box_mask)
```

On its side, the tree is filtered by a function:

```
treeFilter.set_visible_func(self.search_in_reference, None)
```

Now note that the tree is quite big, i have 1-2 thousands of rows, but just 1 level and just few rows (10-20) have 1 level children, so max depth is two.

Well everything works fine, when i type something the tree is filtered as i want, even if i type very fast, so that the refilter() is called twice at the same moment.

Now the problem...if i delete the text in the text entry (with the backspace or with del buttons) i receive the following error by python, repeated a lot of times:

```
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
Exception RuntimeError: 'maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object' in <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'> ignored
Error in sys.excepthook:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Original exception was:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

The error doesn't appear suddenly with the backspace or del buttons, but after some pressures (7-15), also less pressures are needed if i press those buttons faster!

After the errors the plugin continues working but with some problems: the rows with children have been duplicated several times and the filtering function doesn't work well...

Now you can just tell me that i have some recursion problem...but the nice story is that i don't have any recursion anywhere in the code!!!
Maybe is some event triggered by the two buttons del and backspace, but i cannot really understand which is!

I'm getting really crazy!!! please i need help!

Luca

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have an exact solution to your problem, I might be able to help you focus in on what is going wrong.

I have stumbled across the 'maximum recursion depth exceeded' as well, and like your code, there was no recursion anywhere in the code. What had happened was that I had a large set of  very large tree structures holding some data. The code was also multi-processed so that I could build/work with multiple trees simultaneously.
It turned out that the python libraries that deal with passing information back and forth between python processes will pack/unpack that information recursively. So it was when a large tree got passed from one process to the other that I hit the 'maximum recursion depth exceeded'. Even though my own code had no recursion, when the tree structure was passed between the processes, a recursive traversal of the tree occurred to a depth that exceeded the limit.

The solution to my problem was that when the code reached this point of handling these trees, it was forced to run in a single process, which was slower but acceptable. It is also possible to increase the maximum recursion depth, but that is one of those 'do at your own risk' kind of solutions. I would recommend reading up on it before actually doing it. I believe the default depth is 1000 - but you can adjust it with the following:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(new_number)
```

Comment: many thanks aurora!! well i already taken into account to change the recursion limit, but i still didn't tried (i was scared :D).
Anyway about your problem, it seems to be different from mine, because i don't have any additional threads (but i don't know if gtk creates any when handling a signal)...by the way, using only one thread in your code, the error doesn't occur?
I was thinking to use a timer, so the 'live search' doesn't start suddenly after each key pressure, but the Timer in the Threading class seems to be quite crappy for my purpose...

Comment: Remember, threads != processes, and this problem occurred for me with multiple processes. A process is almost like a separate program running, while you can have many threads inside a single process.

Comment: Well i've figure out in which occasion the error occurs...is very strange for me:

the live search starts on typing in a TextEntry, and the error occurs in the search function only when i type something and i delete all the chars but one, with the backspace... that is, 
length of the query = 1 and last key pressed = 'BackSpace'